# Function that takes function with parameters, returns a function with same parameters, but allow no parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes as it's only parameter either:

(A) a function that returns either an object of a specific type or a promise to return it

(B) an object of a specific type

It then returns either:

(C) a function with the same parameters as (A) that returns a promise for another object of a specific type

(D) a promise for another object of a specific type

Here is the code showing how it's implemented:

```
interface Obj{
  a: string,
  b: Promise<number>
}

interface Obj2{
  a: string,
  b: number
}

function Modifier<T>(func: (params: T) => Obj | Promise<Obj>): (params: T) => Promise<Obj2>;
function Modifier<T>(prom: Obj): Promise<Obj2>;
function Modifier<T>(arg1: ((params: T) => Obj | Promise<Obj>) | Obj): ((params: T) => Promise<Obj2>) | Promise<Obj2> {
  if (typeof arg1 === "function") {
    return async (params: T) => {
      const resolved = await arg1(params)
      const resolvedB = await resolved.b
      return {
        a: resolved.a,
        b: resolvedB
      };
    };
  } else {
    const promise = async (): Promise<Obj2> => {
      const resolvedB = await arg1.b
      return {
        a: arg1.a,
        b: resolvedB
      };
    };
    return promise();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to allow parameter (A) to be a function without parameters. But when I plug such a function into my `Modifier` function, it returns a function that requires a parameter:

```
const test = Modifier((): Obj => ({
  a: "",
  b: new Promise((res, rej) => res(2))
}))

const test2 = test()
// Error:
// const test: (params: unknown) => Promise<Obj2>
// Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
// page.ts(121, 65): An argument for 'params' was not provided.
```

If I change the `Modifier` function so that `params` is optional (`params?:`), then it does allows function test2.

However, then it doesn't allow the following:

```
const test = Modifier((arg1: string): Obj => ({
  a: arg1,
  b: new Promise((res, rej) => res(2))
}))

const test2 = test()
// No overload matches this call.
// Overload 1 of 2, '(func: (params?: string | undefined) => Obj | Promise<Obj>): (params?: 
//   string | undefined) => Promise<Obj2>', gave the following error.
//     Argument of type '(arg1: string) => Obj' is not assignable to parameter of type 
//     '(params?: 
//        string | undefined) => Obj | Promise<Obj>'.
//          Types of parameters 'arg1' and 'params' are incompatible.
//            Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//
// Overload 2 of 2, '(prom: Obj): Promise<Obj2>', gave the following error.
//   Argument of type '(arg1: string) => Obj' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Obj'.
//     Type '(arg1: string) => Obj' is missing the following properties from type 'Obj': a, 
//     bts(2769)
```

How can I have the best of both worlds, allowing a function either with our without parameters?

Comment: Both work [in the playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEVRON).

Comment: @md2perpe They want for `test2` to be an error because they aren't providing the params.

Comment: @LindaPaiste. To me it is very unclear what he wants. He writes "The problem is that I would like to allow parameter (A) to be a function without parameters." There's no parameter `A` nor anything labeled "(A)" anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to make the `params` optional because you want the params to be required when `func` has required arguments.

You can simply add an additional overload to handle functions with no arguments.

```
function Modifier(func: () => Obj | Promise<Obj>): () => Promise<Obj2>;
function Modifier<T>(func: (params: T) => Obj | Promise<Obj>): (params: T) => Promise<Obj2>;
function Modifier(prom: Obj): Promise<Obj2>;
function Modifier<T>(arg1: ((params: T) => Obj | Promise<Obj>) | Obj): ((params: T) => Promise<Obj2>) | Promise<Obj2> {
```

If `func` has no arguments then it will match the first overload and no arguments will be required from the modified function.  If `func` *does* have arguments then it matches the second overload and the modified function will return the same arguments as `func`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8jew)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I did try adding an overload, but I put it in the wrong order apparently.

Comment: It has to come before the one for the general function or else that one will always be matched.  You want more specific overloads first since it goes to the first match.